# Why was this question on onward ticket policies closed as opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions

The question [If an airline or immigration policy requires an onward ticket, is it ok to purchase it at the last minute / after being refused check-in/entry?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/154731/1810) was closed as opinion-based and comments were locked.  Why was this question closed as opinion-based?

It seems ok to me as the answer is yes, no,  or it depends on X/X/Z. I don't see any no opinion here. Or do we want to close all questions regarding immigration and airline policy as opinion-based?

Comment: The wording implies to me that it is asking for opinion: "is it ok" in the first sentence in particular. Only after reading it a few times did I realize you were asking it if was allowed or sufficient for airline policies. I think if you edit to reword things like this it could be ok question. Then the problem will be that there are many airlines, so airline X might be ok, airline Y might not.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas thanks for the feedback, I fixed the wording as you suggested.

Answer (score -1):

Because 5 members of the community decided to close and several of them (maybe 2, more likely 3 or more) decided on that reason.

If you are not happy with that decision you can ask for it to be re-opened. And you can add a comment with your argument why it is not opinion based.

I can not say whether it is opinion based or not, but I fear we can not tell what the immigration officers and airline staff will do in the given cases. I see no reason to open based on my view of the question.

Comment: That's why it is difficult to have on-topic questions being reopened, as it requires users to have a lot of reputation points (way more than to be allowed to cast close votes) and some of them are uninterested is salvaging decent content